# How to import just specific instances in haskell

Tags: haskell, module, export, instance, typeclass

I'm facing the following problem: I have multiple instances of a type class defined in a module but don't want to export all of them. How can I do that?

```hs
module SomeModule
  ( calculate
  )
where

class Something a where
  calculate :: a -> Int

instance Something Double where
  calculate x = calculate $ roundToInt x

instance Something Int where
  calculate x = doSomething x

roundToInt :: Double -> Int
roundToInt = round

doSomething :: Int -> Int
doSomething _ = 42
```

In this (simplified) example I have two instances of the type class `Something` which depend on each other, but I just would like to export the instance for `Double`s and not for `Int`s. But in my example, both instances get exported implicitly. Is there a way around it?

Comment: “Is there a way around it?” No. Instances are global in Haskell. You cannot import or export them individually.

Comment: If you don't want the instances to be exported, why write them in the first place? How about just making `Something Int` a function?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin That's what I'm doing right now, but it is very handy to use `Something Int` inside of my module and IMO it also improves naming and readability inside of my module. I was hoping that there is a language extension or so for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the instances you want to hide be on a `newtype` that isn't exported.

```
module SomeModule (calculate) where

newtype NotInt = NotInt Int

class Something a where calculate :: a -> Int
instance Something Double where calculate x = calculate (NotInt (round x))
instance Something NotInt where calculate _ = 42
```

If there are many instances you do not want to export, a parameterized newtype might be less boilerplate.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module SomeModule (calculate) where

newtype Hidden a = Hidden a

class Something a where calculate :: a -> Int
instance Something Double where calculate x = calculate (Hidden (round x :: Int))
instance Something (Hidden Int) where calculate _ = 42
```

Another option is not to define the instance in the first place, and simply use a different name than the class's method name for the implementation of the other method you care about.

```
module SomeModule (calculate) where

class Something a where calculate :: a -> Int
instance Something Double where calculate x = calculateInt (round x)

calculateInt :: Int -> Int
calculateInt _ = 42
```

Comment: Using a parameterized newtype is a pretty good solution. Thank you 